# Inspect state atom which gets updated by a ring handler

Tags: emacs, clojure, ring, cider

**Consider the following scenario:**

A minimal boot task starts up a http server:

```
(boot (serve :handler 'myapp.server/handler
             :port 3000))
```

*(This might be launched in several ways, here it's ok to just run it from a nrepl session, e.g. started by `boot repl` from the terminal)*

The handler is represented by the function `handler` inside the namespace `myapp.server`. The corresponding file looks like this:

```
(ns myapp.server (:require ...))

(defonce server-state (atom {:nr 0}))

(defn handler [req] 
  (prn (swap! server-state update :nr inc))
  {:body "Answer.\n"})
```

This works, every time the address localhost:3000 is visited the the atom is updated and the new version is printed to stdout inside the repl.

How can the atom been inspected at any time?

```
boot.user=> @myapp.server/server-state
```

yields an error. `(...no such var...)`

When trying the same thing from within an emacs cider nrepl connection, this previous attempt always shows up the initial value of the atom: `{:n 0}`

---

**UPDATE**

Here are the exact steps I do when using emacs/cider:

1. `cd` projectdir
2. start `emacs`
3. `cider-jack-in`
4. `(boot (dev))`
5. `Ctrl+C+C` (in order to get a prompt again.)
6. Then Testing with `curl`: getting responses + inside emacs updated atom is logged: `{:n 1}` .. `{:n 2}` ..
7. Then, in the repl: `(require 'myapp.server)`, takes a while: `nil`.
8. finally: `@myapp.server/state` --> however: `{:n 0}`

Comment: Are you sure that your ring handler and your repl are running in the same JVM process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `(...no such var...)` error probably happens because you haven't require the `myapp.server` namespace. Attempts to see updates happening to your atom in CIDER REPL fail probably because your ring app runs in another JVM process than your REPL so the REPL sees only initial value as updates from ring handler happen in another JVM or it is enclosed in a separated classloader as it might be isolated by [boot POD](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Pods).

You have two options:

- start your ring app with REPL server enabled and connect to it from another process [(for example by using Server Socket REPL and connecting to it using telnet)](http://clojure.org/reference/repl_and_main#_launching_a_socket_server)
- start your REPL and then start your ring app from it and you have access to all your loaded namespaces.

With the first approach you probably need to use boot-clj's [`nrepl`](https://github.com/pandeiro/boot-http#-n----nrepl) option. When you configure it to start nREPL server then you can connect to it using `boot repl -c` (optionally providing the same coordinates as to boot-http nrepl options) or [directly from CIDER](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider#connect-to-a-running-nrepl-server) using `cider-connect`.

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is that (boot ..) spawns a new JVM process.

Comment: Yes, it might spawn a new JVM process. You can check the list of JVM processes before and after you execute `(boot (dev))`. It also might be a classpath issue as it uses PODs to isolate tasks dependencies (https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Pods).

Comment: Alright, of course it works if the server is launched immediately from the repl. This is an option in some cases.

Comment: by the way, since it's generally interesting to know: the number of JVM's is still the same after (boot ..) , just tested this.

Comment: the nrepl option of the boot-http task works very well for that purpose. I'll do it this way!