# boot-refresh inside cider-connect

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider, boot-clj

After following the suggested steps at

https://github.com/samestep/boot-refresh

the intended hot-reloading behavior works when using cider-jack-in from inside a boot project.

However, in the following scenario it does not work. consider this boot task:

```clj
(deftask dev2 []
  (comp
   (serve 
    :handler 'app.core/handler
    :reload true
    :port 3000
    :httpkit true
    :nrepl {:port 4000})
 (watch) (refresh) ;; doesn't work with or without this line
))
```

The relevant part is the `:nrepl` keyword.

After this task is fired, one can connect to a nrepl server at port 4000, which has the advantage of accessing the actual state of the application during development. (see this post [for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924779/inspect-state-atom-which-gets-updated-by-a-ring-handler))

This can be done via `cider-connect`. However, in there the hot-reloading is gone. The `:reload true` option might confuse here, this only triggers a source reload when a http request is done. But I'm looking for the more general approach of boot-refresh.

---

*note: The intention here is to have a live-reloading behavior on the server side, which is similar to concepts known on the client side (figwheel or boot-reload).*

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying out my library! :D Are you attempting to reload Clojure code or ClojureScript code?

Comment: In this case it's only about server-side clojure code, that needs to be reloaded. In the final project this will be combined with boot-reload for the client-side cljs reloading.

Comment: I haven't had a lot of experience with `boot-http`; pretty much all I've done with it has been in the context of [Modern ClojureScript](https://github.com/magomimmo/modern-cljs/blob/master/doc/second-edition/tutorial-09.md), at which point I wasn't using `boot-refresh`. Could you add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question that demonstrates the issue you're having?